# Multiple spline series: prevent xAxis from changing when dynamically loading data of one series

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Am trying to display multiple series on a single chart instance and am loading the data asynchronously from FireBase.
In some cases, a single serie is updated while the rest remain unchanged. The expected chart behaviour is a single line changing while the rest remain still.

My implementation is to *remove the first value* in the series data array then *add the newest value*.
In addition to this, I have set the xAxis labels to categorical numbers  i.e
`categories:['01', '02',...]`

The resulting chart ends up zooming out the rest and the updated chart keeps moving out of the categorical bounds.

Here is a fiddle of what is going on: http://jsfiddle.net/Sichangime/fmqozkew/

[image of data updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQEEp.png)

Comment: So you want to have new points within the categories? If so, you need to set new data - remove the first one, shift categories the rest points to the left and add a new point. http://jsfiddle.net/oonjrg4q/

Comment: Thanks a lot @morganfree, didn't think like that before.